# NSInvalidArgumentException - 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values

Tags: ios, string, push-notification, installation, parse-platform

In my view did load I am trying to set a pointer from a user to the installation. Heres a pic of part of my user class. 
[image]

And then I have this code to check if I have set the pointer or not

```
PFInstallation *currentInstalation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

NSString *installationObjectId = currentInstalation.objectId;

if (![currentUser[@"installationString"] isEqual:installationObjectId]) {
     NSLog(@"has not been set");
     //******************
     //THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
     //********************
     currentUser[@"installationString"] = installationObjectId;
}
```

It gives this error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'`

I don't have anything set to nil, which is why am so confused I am just trying to set the installationString key to a string

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem of using bracket notation with a Parse object. Rather than using `currentUser[@"installationString"]` you should use the following:

```
[currentUser objectForKey:@"installationString"]
[currentUser setObject:installationObjectId forKey:@"installationString"];
```

Additionally you need to add the following code. The currentInstallation hasn't been saved yet. I recommend doing this in AppDelegate.

```
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Comment: when i change it for the one inside the if statement i get and error expression is not as singable

Comment: this also gives the same error as in the question `[currentUser setObject:@"installationString" forKey:installationObjectId];`

Comment: You got it backwards. I updated my answer. Drop by [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61287/parse-com).

Answer (score 0):

check if the installation id is null first like this

```
if (installationString == null) {
}
else {
    //save it like this
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```